# Dropna columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to choose columns in `pandas.DataFrame` which contains ALL value in rows bigger than 1000:

```
In [87]: X_NAN = X[X>1000]
In [88]: X_NAN.head()

Out[88]: VAR_0002   VAR_0003    VAR_0004    VAR_0005
           NaN        NaN         10000        NaN
```

Then I want to clean `X_NAN` from NaN values and create new `data.Frame`:

```
In [89]: X_with_big_1000 = X_NAN.dropna(axis=1)
         X_with_big_1000.head()

Out[89]: VAR_0004   VAR_0006    VAR_0007    VAR_0008
           10000     22000       18000       21000
```

But I know and I check it - when I call `dropna` method, he remove value, which should not do. And I try to  `how=Any` and `how=All` -- doesn't help.

Example:

```
In [92]: X_NAN.VAR_0100

Out[92]: ID
         1       100000
         2       200000
         3       300000
         4       400000
Name: VAR_0100, dtype: float64
```

And error:

```
In [93]: X_with_big_1000.VAR_0100

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'VAR_0100'
```

Any advices? May be I should to change my way to choose columns with my definition?

Comment: Try `X_NAN = X[(X>1000).all()]` I think your issue is that some cols will have some `NaN` and when you call `dropna` it will drop any column even if it has a single `NaN` value

Comment: No, I check it, no NaN value in column, but after ```dropna``` column disappears

Comment: @EdChum, ```IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided``` after I add```.all()```

Comment: Building on Ed's answer:  `X_NAN[ X_NAN.columns[ (X_NAN>1000).all() ] ]`

Comment: Yes this is very similar to your previous question if you think about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350114/select-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-by-value-in-rows

Comment: @EdChum, yes, it's true, but now I need to choose element not equals to some specific number, and between or bigger something. Anyway, thank you for help!